# Tkinter trying to destroy a Label defined inside a function after the function has finished

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def spaces(int1,int2):
    if int1 == 1:
        return(int2*"\n")
    else:
        return(int2*" ")
def submitButton():
    subButton_text = subButton.get()
    try:
        informationText.destroy()
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print("an error has occured.")
        print("Attempting to run with the error.")
        pass
    informationText = Label(window, text=subButton_text, bg = "grey",
      fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold")
    informationText.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
    #informationText.destroy()
    #return informationText
def exit_Button():
    window.destroy()

window = Tk()
window.title("Learning tkinter")
window.configure(background="grey")
subButton = StringVar()



#pic1 = PhotoImage(file="test.png")
#Label(window, image=pic1, bg = "grey").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky=W)

Label(window, text="Please enter a value", bg = "grey",
      fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

Entry(window, width=50, bg="white",textvariable=subButton).grid(row=1,column=0,stick=W)
subButton.set("default value")

Button(window, text="Submit", width=10,
       command = submitButton).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)

Label (window, text="\nInformation:", bg="grey", fg="white",
       font="none 12 bold").grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)

Button (window, text="Save\nand exit", width=8,
        command=exit_Button).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=NW)

Label(window, text=spaces(1,10), bg = "grey",
      fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=100,column=0,sticky=W)
Label(window, text=spaces(2,20), bg = "grey",
      fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
window.mainloop()
```

This is my code for a simple tkinter program. When the "submitButton" it creates create a Label called "informationText". But when the button is clicked again with new text I want it to destroy the old text, but it doesn't work. If I destroy the text immediately after creating it (commented out) it works.

Is it because I declared it in a function? If so how can I destroy it after the function has finished?

(first ask, tips appreciated for better questions in the future)

Comment: You only have a reference to the label as long as the `submitButton` function runs. As soon as the function returns, your reference is garbage-collected. You could use a global variable, but why don't you create the label in the main function (together with the other widgets) and only change the text in the `submitButton` function?

Comment: I think for me I would write this in a class so we can do `self.informationtext` as a class attribute. This way the text can be updated at any point.

Answer (score 0):

If you write you code in a class you will be able to use class attributes to store your label and update it later.

Going off what you code is trying to do the below code would be the class equivalent that works. That said I think you should update the label instead of destroying it.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.information_text = None
        self.title("Learning tkinter")
        self.configure(background="grey")
        self.subButton = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Label(self, text="Please enter a value", bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
        tk.Entry(self, width=50, bg="white",textvariable=self.subButton).grid(row=1,column=0,stick="w")

        self.subButton.set("default value")

        tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=10, command = self.submitButton).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky="w")
        tk.Label (self, text="\nInformation:", bg="grey", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=3,column=0, sticky="w")
        tk.Button (self, text="Save\nand exit", width=8, command=self.exit_Button).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="nw")
        tk.Label(self, text=self.spaces(1,10), bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=100,column=0,sticky="w")
        tk.Label(self, text=self.spaces(2,20), bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")

    def spaces(self, int1, int2):
        if int1 == 1:
            return(int2*"\n")
        else:
            return(int2*" ")
    def submitButton(self):

        try:
            self.information_text.destroy()
            self.information_text = None
        except:
            print("an error has occured.")
            print("Attempting to run with the error.")

        self.information_text = tk.Label(self, text=self.subButton.get(), bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold")
        self.information_text.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="w")

    def exit_Button(self):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

My 2nd example will use `config()` to update the label instead of having to destroy it. I think this might work better for your needs here.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)


        self.title("Learning tkinter")
        self.configure(background="grey")
        self.subButton = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Label(self, text="Please enter a value", bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
        tk.Entry(self, width=50, bg="white",textvariable=self.subButton).grid(row=1,column=0,stick="w")

        self.subButton.set("default value")

        tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=10, command = self.submitButton).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky="w")
        tk.Label (self, text="\nInformation:", bg="grey", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=3,column=0, sticky="w")
        tk.Button (self, text="Save\nand exit", width=8, command=self.exit_Button).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="nw")
        tk.Label(self, text=self.spaces(1,10), bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=100,column=0,sticky="w")
        tk.Label(self, text=self.spaces(2,20), bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")

        self.information_text = tk.Label(self, text="", bg = "grey", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold")
        self.information_text.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="w")

    def spaces(self, int1, int2):
        if int1 == 1:
            return(int2*"\n")
        else:
            return(int2*" ")
    def submitButton(self):
        self.information_text.config(text=self.subButton.get())

    def exit_Button(self):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()
```